# Monitor.TryEnter would not return false

Tags: c#, .net

The follow code is my testing code.

```
    public class Test
    {
        public async Task Lock(object _lock)
        {
            if (!Monitor.TryEnter(_lock)) {
                Console.WriteLine("locked");
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("entered");
            await Task.Delay(99999);
            Monitor.Exit(_lock);
            Console.WriteLine("exited");
        }
    }
    static async Task Main()
    {
        var _lock= new object();
        var test = new Test();
        do {
            test.Lock(_lock);
            Thread.Sleep(999);
        } while (true);
    }
```

I expect it should show like as folowing

```
entered
locked
locked
...
exited
entered
locked
locked
...
exited
```

But I got

```
entered
entered
entered
...
exited
```

It means `Monitor.TryEnter(_lock)` is always true and not locking.

Is that because I am using the Task instead of the Thread?

If yes, how should I do?

Comment: Doesn't your IDE complain about CS1998?

Comment: @NPras I tried, but it does not work.

Comment: @shingo No, my IDE doesn't complain about CS1998.

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS. It doesn't do what you think it does. Locks are acquired by a specific thread, tasks can hop threads at each `await`. You'll need a totally different mechanism that isn't a simple `lock` (or `Monitor.TryEnter()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of using an async method (Lock) with an infinite loop `(do while(true))` in your Main method. The await Task `Delay(99999);` inside the Lock method is causing the method to be asynchronous and returns a Task. Because you're not awaiting the Lock method in your Main method, it doesn't wait for the task to complete and continues iterating in the loop.

To achieve the expected behavior, you can modify your code to properly await the Lock method and use a SemaphoreSlim instead of Monitor for locking. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
public class Test
{
    private SemaphoreSlim _lock = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

    public async Task Lock()
    {
        await _lock.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("entered");
            await Task.Delay(99999);
        }
        finally
        {
            _lock.Release();
            Console.WriteLine("exited");
        }
    }
}

static async Task Main()
{
    var test = new Test();
    do
    {
        await test.Lock();
        await Task.Delay(999);
    } while (true);
}
```

Comment: I think it would be important to mention that Locks, and Monitor can be entered multiple times while on the same thread. And in the OPs example `Monitor.TryEnter` will always run on the same thread, and therefore always succeed.